# HTML table going beyond asp.net master page content margin

Tags: asp.net, html, css, vb.net, master-pages

I have a table with 9 columns in an asp.net(vb) master page. The cells are supposed to hold textboxes. But even without textboxes, they are going beyond the content margins. So what can be done to make them fit the master page margins and if still it does not fits, the content area should become scrollable(not the whole page!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using asp.net Panel control worked for me. It automatically added the scroll pane on the edges and bottom of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS attributes *width* and *[overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow-x)* on the table... assuming it's an ASP.Net control table, and not plain HTML, then it would look like this:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    table.mytable {
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }
</style>

<asp:Table CssClass="mytable">
    <%-- table stuff  --%>
</asp:Table>
```

If it's a regular HTML table:

```
<table style="width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll">
    <!-- table stuff -->
</table>
```

Comment: OOPS! It gives a validation error :Validation (CSS 2.1):overflow-x is not a known CSS property name.Also note that it is a plain HTML table!

Comment: @rahulserver it's supported on all major browsers, even IE.  I don't know why Visual Studio's Intellisense doesn't recognize it.